# Library and Packaging - Unknown

Tags: playframework

I have create a play framework project. I have created a lib folder and add 2 jars to the lib directory.

When running via intellij and SBT compiles fine...However it is not picking up after the application is up.

Problems:

```
#1 - How to make it work or the way to add the jar in runtime which is present in the lib folder?
#2 - Also, how to add the libraries in the lib folder and package the app as exe or one executable jar?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is anyone is there to help me?

Comment: 1. Please, only one question per problem. Split those two question. 2. What do you mean by "However it is not picking up after the application is up." What is your application supposed to pick up. -> Edit your question. Remove the second question and provide more information about what your application is supposed to do and how it fails at that.